# Can an XML attribute be the empty string?

Tags: xml

Can an XML attribute be the empty string?

In other words, is

```
<element att="" />
```

valid XML?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create an empty attribute via
    attname=""

You can create an empty element via

```
<elementName></elementName>
```

or

```
<elementName/>
```

Answer (score 12):

Yes, this is well-formed XML.

An easy way to test this (on Windows) is to save the sample in a `test.xml` file and open it with Internet Explorer. IE will display an error message if the document is not well-formed.

Comment: I'm not sure I would rely on IE as the definitve test of a standard.

Comment: Don't worry about it:  testing well-formed xml is something that's pretty well understood and hard to screw up.

Comment: As @hal10001 noted, there are several parsers that fail when given valid XML and I expect that there are several that work with invalid XML.

Answer (score 4):

It is worth nothing that this is an XML *attribute*, not an element. An empty element would be:

```
</>
```

which is not valid XML.

Comment: You're correct, I've edited the question to match what I intended.

Comment: If we're being pedantic, the XML spec calls elements such as `<br></br>` and `<br/>` empty elements.

Answer (score 4):

this is valid xml tag:

```
<mytag myattrib=""/>
```

this is not:

```
<mytag myattrib/>
```

Answer (score 2):

It should also be noted that some XML parsers will throw an error on empty string nodes and attributes instead of returning null or an empty string. So even though it might be valid, it would be better to leave it out altogether.

Comment: That sounds like a broken parser, since a missing attribute is different from an attribute specifying an empty string (particularly when using a DTD that specifies default attribute values).

Comment: REXML for Ruby throws Nil, which isn't as bad as returning an empty string, and if memory serves, SimpleXML returns an empty SimpleXML object on an empty node instead of either.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - element content can be empty, and as you used in your question there's even the special Empty-Element tag notation:

```
<elementname />
```

Except when interop with SGML is necessary, the above is equivalent to

```
<elementname></elementname>
```

Attribute values can also be empty, but attributes must always be followed by an '=' and a quoted string, even if the string contains no characters.

---

The definitive place for this
    information is the XML spec: 
    http://www.xml.com/axml/testaxml.htm

Here's what the Annotated XML Reference has to say about empty elements:

> So, is this: `<img
>   src='madonna.gif'></img>` really
>   exactly the same as `<img
>   src='madonna.gif'/>`? As far as XML is
>   concerned, they are. This decision was
>   the occasion of much religious debate,
>   with some feeling that there is an
>   essential element between "point" and
>   "container" type elements. And as the
>   "for interoperability" note below
>   makes clear, if you are using pre-1998
>   SGML software to process XML, there is
>   a big difference.

**note:** the discussion on empty elements was due to the original wording of the posted question.