# dom parser throws error when attribute doesn't have value

Tags: javascript, html

```
htmlStr = '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" data-autoplay><div>'
node = new DOMParser().parseFromString(htmlStr, "text/xml");
```

Above code throws error because `data-autoplay` doesnt have any value.
How can make it run?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926442/is-an-xml-attribute-without-a-value-valid

Comment: because of creates <body> tage as well